# Какой вариант лучше (тире или двоеточие, НЕ слитно или раздельно)?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно, тире-или-двоеточие

Даны **два варианта оформления предложения.** В принципе верны оба, но какой и почему подходит лучше?

(1) *Вариантов со стороны родственников было **не много** – пойдёшь в юристы.*

(2) *Вариантов со стороны родственников было **немного:** пойдёшь в юристы.*

**Дополнение**

Просили проверить правильность варианта (1). Все единодушно (7 голосов) исправили его на вариант (2). Мне это не понравилось...

Comment: Что с согласованием времён? *Было не много — пошёл. Есть не много — пойдёшь.* *Какой вариант лучше* — всего четыре варианта (2x2). Вы два исключаете? И ещё: а смысл в двоеточии?

Comment: Дополнила вопрос, больше ничего не знаю. Я хотела оставить (1), а теперь думаю... А времена такие. Это ему (рассказчику) так сказали: пойдешь в юристы.

Comment: *Вариантов... было не много* — а они куда-то делись? Почему "было"?

Comment: *но какой и почему подходит лучше?* — здесь очень любопытный случай, вот такое надо учёным разбирать. "Почему" ссылается на "какой подходит лучше", не стоит ссылаться на то, что ещё не завершено, стилистика нарушается. Да и вопрос вклинивается в другой, надо так: *но какой, и почему, подходит лучше?* Как-то и не сталкивался с тем, чтоб один вопрос был внутри другого.

Comment: Я понимаю так: это отрывок из текста. Вроде бы обсуждалось будущее молодого человека. Говорили много, но придумали не много – всего-то один вариант  (в юристы).

Comment: Если делают вывод сейчас (судя по "пойдёшь"), то с вариантами ничего не случилось, они не не были, а есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примечания:

1) *Пойдёшь в юристы* — **это не вариант**, а вывод. И это ключевой пункт. Двоеточие могли захотеть поставить, чтобы перечислить варианты.
Вариант — это так:
*Вариантов со стороны родственников было немного: **пойти** в юристы.*
Ещё кое-как подходит такой, разговорный вариант:
*Вариантов со стороны родственников было немного: **идёшь** в юристы или в программисты.*
Для такой формы необходимо хотя бы два варианта (чтоб был понятным смысл).

2) *Немного* — это никак не один. Ну хотя бы уже два должно быть. Не говорят так люди про один. Ну или сделать переход к одному:
*Вариантов со стороны родственников было немного, а точнее, лишь один...*
Честно говоря, и подумать не мог, что смысл в том, что они придумали только один вариант.

3) Тире для выражения следствия:
*Вариантов со стороны родственников было не много – из-за этого пойдёшь в юристы.*
Пойдёт в юристы из-за того, что не было больше вариантов? В этом мало логики. Как будто родственники решали его судьбу, как судьи. Следствие частичное, оно сомнительное. Как ни странно, этот вариант наиболее корректный, особенно грамматически. Тире может быть интонационным, но такое тире не надо использовать там, где есть хоть какое-то следствие, чтоб не было каши (двусмысленности).

4) Если следствие (тире), то чётко ощущается отрицание: *рассчитывали, что будет много, а оказалось не так (не много)*, а если перечисление — то "немного" как обобщающее слово.

5) При "перечислении" одного варианта (если так можно выразиться) двоеточие плохо подходит. Тогда гораздо лучше тире, оно как раз и используется, когда элементов один или два. А двоеточие, как правило, подготавливает к тому, что элементов будет много (три и больше).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129218/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd--------).